# Calculate count of related nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query which returns the name and id of categories but I also want the photo count related to that category. Is there a way to calculate the photo count and return with the bundle

```
MATCH (user:User {id:"xyz"),
       (root:Category {id:"123"})
MATCH path=(user)<-[:OWNER]-(photo)-[:PHOTO_OF]->(categories)
WITH distinct categories as cats, user, photo
MATCH catpath=(cats)<-[:CHILD_OF*]-(root)
WHERE photo.is_private=false
WITH [x in nodes(catpath) | x.id] as p, root, catpath, user
WHERE p[-1] = "123"
return distinct [x in nodes(catpath) | [x.id, x.name]] as paths
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH
    (user:User {id:"xyz"}),
    (root:Category {id:"123"}),
    path=(user)<-[:OWNER]-(photo)-[:PHOTO_OF]->(categories)
WHERE photo.is_private=false
WITH DISTINCT categories as cats, root, COUNT(photo) AS count
MATCH catpath=(cats)<-[:CHILD_OF*]-(root)
RETURN {numPhotos: count, path: [x in nodes(catpath) | {id: x.id, name: x.name}]} AS result;
```

I have cleaned up the query as well, to make it more efficient and to remove redundant checks.